# Extract the input parameters from the string using regex into parameter and value group

Tags: regex, expression, regex-group, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I need help extracting/splitting these parameters within the string using regex into parameter and value groups.

```
Input -> collection_a=['U1', 'U2'], collection_b=['U1', 'U2']

output -> Group Parameter = collection_a
          Group Value = ['U1', 'U2']

          Group Parameter = collection_b
          Group Value = ['U1', 'U2']
```

```
Input -> collection=['U1', 'U2'], callback_macro=utils.user_email(user_id=$$)

output -> Group Parameter = collection
          Group Value = ['U1', 'U2']

          Group Parameter = callback_macro
          Group Value = utils.user_email(user_id=$$)
```

```
Input -> collection=['U1', 'U2'], callback_macro=utils.user_email(user_id=$$, config={'user': 'ADMIN'})

output -> Group Parameter = collection
          Group Value = ['U1', 'U2']

          Group Parameter = callback_macro
          Group Value = utils.user_email(user_id=$$)
```

```
Input -> collection=['U1','U2'], callback_macro=string.replace(value=$$, pattern=^(.*)$, replacement={'user': $1})

output -> Group Parameter = collection
          Group Value = ['U1', 'U2']

          Group Parameter = callback_macro
          Group Value = string.replace(value=$$, pattern=^(.*)$, replacement={'user': $1})
```

I'm using this Regex `/((\s*(?<parameter>[a-z_]+)\s*=\s*(?<value>((?!(,\s*[a-z_]+)\s*=\s*).)*)),{1,})/g` and it works perfectly in case 1 and case 2 but breaks in case 3 & 4 as in case 3 & 4 it contains `=`  within the argument's value.

Regex link - https://regex101.com/r/U2CaLb/1

Comment: Looking at the data, you might have balanced parenthesis, and the `pattern=` part can contain a regex which can also contain all kinds of brackets, braces, parenthesis etc.. You might use a pattern that excludes certain words but it will be still brittle `(?<parameter>\w+)=(?<value>.*?(?=,(?!\s*(?:pattern\b|replacement\b|['"]))|$))` https://regex101.com/r/d7VLYA/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. but these arguments (pattern, replacement)are dynamic so I can't hardcode that in the regex

Comment: You may need to add a balanced pattern to handle opening and closing of arrays, function calls, objects, so handle balanced `[]`, `()` and `{}` with the help of recursion. This might help you : https://regex101.com/r/tC6vM5/1

Comment: Thanks for the link @PatrickJanser. I tried but I couldn’t solve it. Can you help me with the regex? -  https://regex101.com/r/U2CaLb/1

Comment: @Abhishek I tried until I came to this case: What happens if the value is a string containing some chars such as a comma, brackets or anything else? Then even a well-prepared balanced pattern will not be able to handle it! It's too complicated to handle all the cases.

Comment: @PatrickJanser that's right I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very difficult to do a split with these requirements.
You could just match *key/value* and put them into an array.
Note that the third input sample does not follow the other ones pattern.

Here are some options to choose from.

***Method 1***  This regex uses a single level braces matching as part of it.

```
(\w+)=((?:\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)|{.*?}|[^,\r\n])*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fnPb6e/1

```
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 =
 (                             # (2 start)
    (?:
       \[ .*? \] 
     | \( .*? \) 
     | { .*? } 
     | 
       [^,\r\n] 
    )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

For *Balanced braces text*, PCRE or Not-Net engines :

***Method 2***  This regex is the simple version as nesting of `()`,`[]`,`{}`
where the balanced end is independently found to completion.

```
(\w+)=((?:(\[(?:[^\[\]]++|(?3))*\])|(\((?:[^()]++|(?4))*\))|({(?:[^{}]++|(?5))*})|[^,\r\n])*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/dgWMDZ/1

```
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 =
 (                             # (2 start)
    (?:
       (                             # (3 start)
          \[
          (?:
             [^\[\]]++ 
           | (?3)
          )*
          \]
       )                             # (3 end)
     | (                             # (4 start)
          \(
          (?:
             [^()]++ 
           | (?4)
          )*
          \)
       )                             # (4 end)
     | (                             # (5 start)
          {
          (?:
             [^{}]++ 
           | (?5)
          )*
          }
       )                             # (5 end)
     | [^,\r\n]
    )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

***Method 3***  This regex will balance the different braces nested inside
each other if applicable. This will allow for more internal brace structure
items and is probably not needed for this scenario, but could be in the future.
This is the enhanced *Method 2* version and encompasses that functionality.

```
(\w+)=((?:(\[(?:[^\[\](){}]++|(?3))*\]|\((?:[^\[\](){}]++|(?3))*\)|{(?:[^\[\](){}]++|(?3))*})|[^,\r\n])*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZubSke/1

```
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 =
 (                             # (2 start)
    (?:
       (                             # (3 start)
          \[ 
          (?:
             [^\[\](){}]++ 
           | (?3) 
          )*
          \] 
        | 
          \( 
          (?:
             [^\[\](){}]++ 
           | (?3) 
          )*
          \) 
        | 
          {
          (?:
             [^\[\](){}]++ 
           | (?3) 
          )*
          }
       )                             # (3 end)
     | 
       [^,\r\n] 
    )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

***Method 4***  Same as method 3 and added handling of simple single or double quoted strings.
This regex will blend in quote parsing within any other delimiter pair
balance, as well as outside of these delimiters.
Note that there is a pass through, garbage collector `[^,\r\n]` to get catch unbalanced
delimiters. This is by design as balanced text is really just a suggestion during the fleshing out process.

```
(\w+)=((?:(\[(?:[^\[\](){}'"]++|(?4)|(?3))*\]|\((?:[^\[\](){}'"]++|(?4)|(?3))*\)|{(?:[^\[\](){}'"]++|(?4)|(?3))*})|('[^'\r\n]*?'|"[^"\r\n]*?")|[^,\r\n])*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/090iI7/1

```
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 =
 (                             # (2 start)
    (?:
       (                             # (3 start)
          \[ 
          (?:
             [^\[\](){}'"]++ 
           | (?4) 
           | (?3) 
          )*
          \] 
        | 
          \( 
          (?:
             [^\[\](){}'"]++ 
           | (?4) 
           | (?3) 
          )*
          \) 
        | 
          {
          (?:
             [^\[\](){}'"]++ 
           | (?4) 
           | (?3) 
          )*
          }
       )                             # (3 end)
     | (                             # (4 start)
          ' [^'\r\n]*? '
        | 
          " [^"\r\n]*? "
       )                             # (4 end)
     | 
       [^,\r\n] 
       
    )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Comment: Thanks, @sln once again. You saved my day. These expressions look complex to understand for me  but it worked for all the above cases perfectly 

Comment: I ran into the same problem as @PatrickJanser described above. I'm having difficulties handling if the value is a string containing some chars such as a comma. 
Input -> `string_a='U1, U2', string_b='["U1", "U2"]'`

Comment: Added method 4 that handles quotes.